# Why is there no Pi-backbonding in BeCl2?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond, bent-bond

The $\ce{Cl}$ atoms in $\ce{BeCl2}$ donate a lone pair to the $\ce{Be}$ atom of another molecule so that Beryllium can complete its octet.
[image: BeCl2]

What I don't understand is why don't the $\ce{Cl}$ atoms donate the lone pair to the $\ce{Be}$ of the same molecule and form $\pi-$backbonds?

Comment: So your asking why BeCl2 isn't monomeric in solid phase? Related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/21764/which-lewis-structure-for-becl2-is-more-commonly-seen