# What does the molecular orbital scheme of beryllium chloride and hydride look like?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, halides

Beryllium is a somewhat fascinating element since it is the only member of the second group that behaves somewhat non-metalish and, e.g. forms a somewhat covalent chloride and a covalent hydride.

In an answer to a different and unrelated question, I tried guessing what the bonding picture of $\ce{BeCl2}$ would be. Given the monomer’s linear shape, I was inclined to assume something that introduces a four-electron-three-centre bond, which has the nice side-advantage of allowing beryllium to contribute to bonding orbitals using its s orbital only. However, I would guess that the more traditional picture would include two $\mathrm{sp^2}$ type bonds to the neighbouring chlorines and then a nonzero amount of π backbonding making the MO similar to that of $\ce{CO2}$.

What *does* the actual, calculated MO scheme of $\ce{BeCl2}$ look like; what does $\ce{BeH2}$’s look like, how do they compare and what can we learn from them concerning the bonding properties of beryllium?

Comment: Given that you're the one asking this, I assume you are looking for a quantitative (computational) MO diagram as opposed to the simple qualitative one, which isn't really difficult to derive.

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/21764/which-lewis-structure-for-becl2-is-more-commonly-seen/21786#21786

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/22088/dimers-and-polymers-of-electron-deficient-compounds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I calculated molecular orbitals for $\ce{BeCl2}$ at MP2/jun-cc-pVDZ level of theory; given below are the doubly occupied MOs at this level of theory along with their symmetry designations and energy in a.u. For some reason my Avogadro kept crashing when I tried to select an iso value I thought appropriate for the last two MOs; anyway these are completely localised $\ce{Be}$ atoms. If we look at the 8 valence orbitals, there is indeed delocalised $\pi$ bonding as you suggest, and do bear a striking resemblance to MOs for $\ce{CO2}$.

For $\ce{BeH2}$ I again ran into trouble generating nice visuals using the cube file in Avogadro. I will update this post with visuals as soon as possible (It would be great if someone can help out).

I got the following doubly occupied MOs at MP2/jun-cc-pVDZ level of theory:      -4.644660 ($\ce{a_g}$) ;     -0.504366  ($\ce{a_g}$) ;  -0.469857  ($\ce{b_{3u}}$). However, it is evident from the symmetry designations that $\pi$-type orbitals aren't involved in bonding.

P.S: If you are interested, I can provide the input, output, and cube files on request.

[image]